# Error on including a file in directive in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, url, exception

I am trying to `include` a JSP page using directive in another JSP.

My code is:

```
<%@include file="${pageContext.request.contextPage}/Pages/Loader/
load-resources.jsp" %>
```

As you can see here clearly that my url should be like

```
localhost://port/WebApp1/Pages/Loader/load-resources.jsp
```

But on execution i am receiving this error which says this URL does not exist. But i passed url in reference from contextPage.

```
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6117: File 
"/Pages/Test/Take/${pageContext.request.contextPage}/Pages/Loader/
load-resources.jsp" not found
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does EL work anywhere else on the page? I'm not even sure you can use EL in directives like that. Why do you even *need* to, can't you just use the absolute path?

Comment: What is EL @DaveNewton ? and isn't contextPage returns starting of absolute path? I don't think the whole url is relative.

Comment: EL is simply `${...}` way of accessing to variables.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Can you post an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you want to include `Pages/Loader/load-resources.jsp`, simply use :

```
<%@include file="/Pages/Loader/load-resources.jsp" %>
```

You do not include an URL, but a *file*. The root of the hierarchy is simply the root of your web application.

By the way, are you aware of the differences between the directive `<%@include ... %>` and the tag `<jsp:include .../>` :

- with the directive, you include the source file, meaning all page context variables will be shared
- with `<jsp:include .../>`, you include at output level, meaning each page will have its own page context